# ElementClickInterceptedException: Element is not clickable at point because another element obscures it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy tratando de hacer una automatización con Selenium en recaptcha de google pero  a pesar de que le doy tiempo a la página para que se cargue completamente no logra encontrar el elemento para continuar con la prueba. Quiero que le de click al botón de no soy un robot.
Este es mi código y no tengo idea a qué se puede deber.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import time

chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_option.add_argument('incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\dchrome\chromedriver.exe', 
options=chrome_option)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[5]').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `find_element_by_id` :

```
driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-demo').click()
```

o bien puedes ejecutar código `javascript` de la siguiente manera:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('recaptcha-demo').click();")
```

De todas formas debes tener en cuenta que usar `time.sleep` no es recomendable, ya que solo espera el tiempo solicitado para ejecutar una acción independientemente del comportamiento de los elementos dentro del DOM. Te invito a revisar [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Si estas usando modo `headless`, una vez que hayas ejecutado el `click` puedes comprobar haciendo una captura de pantalla `driver.save_screenshot('test.png')`, y te mostrará lo que ha realizado.

Cuando te encuentras con estos problemas, lo mejor siempre es revisar el código *html* que obtienes de la página luego de hacer `driver.get(url)`. Para ello debes hacer `print(driver.page_source)`

Comment: Gracias amigo la primera opción me funcionó. Pero ahora no encuentro el botón para seleccionar el botón de challenge de audio, me parece por lo que es una ventana emergente.

Comment: mmm, es de la misma página o es otra?, puedes publicar una pregunta nueva si lo ves necesario

Comment: Cuando das click en el botón de "No soy un robot" aparece como una ventana emergente para seleccionar las imágenes que corresponde al desafío pero en la parte de abajo también hay varios botones, uno de ellos sirve para realizar el captcha pero por audio, ese botón es el que quiero ubicar, lo busco por xpath y no lo encuentra que me recomiendas para buscarlo??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715178/click-on-captcha-via-selenium-always-raised-picture-verification Revisa esta publicación